# Windows 7 Backup & Restore - Are files deleted from the source also removed from the archive?

Tags: windows-7, windows, backup, file-management, windows-7-backup

I use windows 7 backup tool for backing up my files. Now I want know what happens if I delete a file in its original place? will it stay in backup? (not full backup, updated backup).

There in windows documentary is: *"When you use the Back Up Files wizard, Windows keeps track of which files and folders are new or modified. Then, when you make a new backup, you can back up ... just the files that have changed since the last time you made a backup."*

**1- what it does with deleted files if I just update the backup?**

**2- And if It doesn't delete them from updated backup file so how can I delete them?** ( I don't like to do a full backup again because of huge size of files)

Answer (score 1):

1) Windows 7 Backup and Restore will do nothing with deleted files if you update the backup.

Your backup will be updated with new files and new versions of existing files.  Files that you deleted from your computer will remain in your archive.  You can always recover deleted files from your backup as show here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Recover-lost-or-deleted-files

2) Go into your archive and manually delete the files.

I can't find any literature that says this causes issues, but I'm not 100% sure of that.  Backups are saved in this format: \\Backup Set  .  Go into the folder and delete the files you don't want.